# 503 Service Unavailable in Mule

Tags: java, arrays, json, http, mule-studio

I am getting 503 Service Unavailable when call in Mule application...  Call is not reaching to HTTP Listener I think and beside of HTTP Listener there is Set Variable... to Set Variable also not reaching call...  Till day before yesterday it was working in all work spaces but suddenly it is not reaching to listener when I was trying after putting debug mode.  But for other developer is not having any issue and he is able to receive call to Listener and other components.  Current configurations everything is good. Can you please suggest what needs to check.

Comment: 503 sounds like proxy report - and probably missconfigured

Comment: You need to provide more details of the issue. Is it in the same server? Are you using API Manager? Your application implements the listener or the requester? What does an HTTP wire logging shows?

Comment: Same application with 2 days or earlier created workspace working and receiving call from listener but just yesterday and today when I checkout code from bitbucket and import into new or old workspace then not receiving calls to Http listener.

Comment: for my colleague it is working when he checkout code from bitbucket and import into new old workspace.... he is receiving call through http listener...  listener configuration for both are same as both are using same bitbucket branch/version.  I am using Anypoint studio for testing. And no logging in console as at least call is not coming inside of the flow through listener when i test from postman and soap ui

Comment: If I create now just sample mule app just to see httplistener by placing httplistener and logger and deployed then i am receiving call from listener.

Comment: I have to resolve why existing mule project not able to receive calls from http listener.  Please help to guide on this.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when I added an autodiscovery configuration for my application. Adding this to VM arguments folved my issue.

```
-Danypoint.platform.gatekeeper=disabled
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem.
Everything was working, and suddenly (don't know why) I received the same 503 response.

I tried a lot to figure out what was going on.
Added new listeners and tested existing flows, which all went well.
Only my particular listener with the APIKit was never getting reached anymore.

I also disabled 'the gatekeeper' as suggested in the following article :
[API-returns-503-Service-Unavailable-error-to-clients](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/API-returns-503-Service-Unavailable-error-to-clients)
[Run -> Run configurations -> tab Arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6mgl.png)

I exported the project to a deployable archive file, with the checkbox 'only export project sources' selected. Tested this application on different PC's which went well.
Created a new workspace on my PC, imported the file , and the application failed again.

After a few other try & errors, I enabled the 'clear application data' -> 'prompt' selection box, and I disabled the 'APIKit settings' -> 'Show APIKit consol'.
I'm not sure if that consol had something to do with it, but after restarting the application and select YES on **Clear application data** , it worked well again.
[Run configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnOmH.png)

I re-enabled the 'show APIKit consol' again, and it still worked fine.

This should solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is basically the same answer as the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66800483/11417027) provided by [user15476634](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15476634/user15476634), but with a visual description, and reasons why this error may occur.

For those who are wondering where to find Clear Application Data, please see below screenshot.
[image]

Most usual suspects in these type of issues is corrupted Application data due to following issues:

- Trying to open multiple test consoles at a time
- Working on huge payload and not enough memory allocated
- Accidentally selecting the multiple run configurations and/or debug configurations at once
- when you try to re-run the same app while an instance is already
  running by disregarding the prompt/warning window (Do you want to stop the running application and start ...?)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had the same experience, the 503s appeared out of nowhere.  Clearing application data did not work for me, setting

```
-Danypoint.platform.gatekeeper=disabled
```

did not work for me.  I had to remove this xml tag from my global config

```
<api-gateway:autodiscovery ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after turning on autodiscovery in order to deploy, so i had to remove these lines (autodiscovery) temporary then test then return these lines back in order to deploy

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add the -Danypoint.platform.gatekeeper=disabled line just fine in Anypoint 7.11.1.  When I moved to 7.13.0, nothing worked including clearing application data.  The thing that fixed it for me was simply removing the other run configurations and creating a new one with gatekeeper=disabled line.  Then everything ran as it should.  Hindsight, removing the other configurations probably wasn't needed.  I was being overly cautious at that point.